# How to apply inhalable poison?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, poison

There are four categories of poison: contact, ingested, inhaled, and injury. I'm interested in inhaled. For example, there's a [poison](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison) (inhaled) called [Burnt Othor Fumes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison/burnt-othur-fumes). Let's say I craft some. How do I go about using it in combat?

Comment: Rule #1: Stand upwind.

Answer (score 3):

## [FROM YOUR LINK](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/afflictions/poison)

> Inhaled: These poisons are delivered the moment a creature enters an area containing such poisons and do not usually have an onset time. F**or most inhaled poisons, 1 dose fills a volume equal to a 10-foot cube.** A creature can attempt to hold its breath while inside the area to avoid inhaling the toxin. A creature holding its breath receives a 50% chance of not having to make a Fortitude save each round. See the rules for holding your breath and suffocation. If a creature is holding its breath and fails the constitution check to continue doing so, rather than suffocating it begins to breathe normally again (and is subject to the effects of the inhaled poison if still in the area). (Emphasis Mine)

As we can see, it fills a ten foot cube. This does not mean 10 cubic feet, but rather an area 10*10*10.

From there, you either open the stopper (which releases the poison around you), or use it as a ranged splash weapon (which releases it around your opponent).

Comment: This is a strong suggestion. The RAW do not say anything of the actual delivery mechanism. One could argue that it is a 2-component-system, i.e. you need something to deliver the poison with (like a powder, smockestick, pepper pellet,...).